# Button on Hover shows boxShadow in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, button

I want this button to show `boxShadow` only at `Hover`. How to do that ?

Button code:

```
<CButton
        style={{
          float: 'right',
          marginBottom: '15px',
          marginRight: '30px',
          backgroundColor: '#06ac06',
          border: 'none',
          boxShadow: '0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)',
        }}
</CButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-classes like `:hover` are not available as inline style. You can implement the hover behavior in JS through a React `state` + `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` listeners (and then set the `box-shadow` value based on the `state`). But as you can see, this approach requires too much boilerplate. I would suggest using CSS-in-JS library like styled-components, utility class like Tailwind, or SCSS.

Try this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-morning-s5sh64?file=/src/App.js

````
const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false)

//...

<CButton
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}
        style={{
          float: 'right',
          marginBottom: '15px',
          marginRight: '30px',
          backgroundColor: '#06ac06',
          border: 'none',
          transition: 'box-shadow .3s', //added for Smouth transition
          boxShadow: `5px 5px 18px -3px rgba(0,0,0,${isHover ? 0.27 : 0})`,
        }}
      >
      </CButton>
```
````

Comment: thanks for the sinppet, it helped me resolve my issue.
the actual problem was related to the logic of boxshadow appearing. i changed: 
`boxShadow: isHover ? '5px 5px 18px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.27)' : 0,`

to : 
`boxShadow: '5px 5px 18px -3px rgba(0,0,0,${isHover ? 0.27 : 0})',`

But i still dont know what 0.27 does?

Comment: @dark `0` is not a valid value for `box-shadow` (a valid one is `none`, if you were going with the original solution).
The fourth value of `rgba` is the `alpha`, or the transparency of the color. Setting it to 0 makes the `box-shadow` transparent.